# Is there a spell that grants the ability to see in both magical and non-magical darkness?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, vision-and-light, content-identification

I'm looking for a spell which I thought existed, but now I'm unable to find it. The main effect of the spell was to grant the see-in-darkness ability (darkvision + see in magical darkness, both with no range limit much like normal vision).

The only spell which I can find is *true seeing*, which is a high-level spell.

Comment: @HeyICanChan I read that spell but it makes no sense, its more powerful than darkvision at 2nd level

Comment: @HeyICanChan I can understand why its rare. Makes any ranged attacker much more powerful at night. Since I am building a archer, being able to attack all night at range is a very powerful ability.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Spells that will grant [See in Darkness](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules/#TOC-See-in-Darkness-Su-):

- [Share Senses](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/share-senses/) (wizard 4, witch 3) with an [Imp Familiar](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/devil/imp/) (obtained through [Improved Familiar](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/improved-familiar/) or [archetypes](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/prestige-classes/other-paizo/c-d/diabolist/));
- The *Nightmare dragon* form from [Form of The Alien-Dragon](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/f/form-of-the-alien-dragon/) (wizard 6) from [Legacy of Dragons Player Companion](http://paizo.com/products/btpy9nfl?Pathfinder-Player-Companion-Legacy-of-Dragons);
- The *Fiendish* aspect of [Divine Vessel](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/divine-vessel/) (oracle 8);

Spells that will allow to see in the darkness of any kind, but do not grant the special ability:

- [Eyes in The Void](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/e/eyes-of-the-void/) (wizard 4);
- [True Seeing](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/t/true-seeing/) (cleric 5, wizard 6);

Not a spell, but also worth considering:

- [Shadow Eyes Piercings (Greater)](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules/#TOC-See-in-Darkness-Su-) grant See in Darkness and are always on.

Answer (score 5):

I can't find a spell that matches everything you describe. There are the Darkvision and Greater Darkvision spells, but those only grant you regular darkvision, not the ability to see in supernatural darkness like you're describing. The [Eyes of the Void](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/e/eyes-of-the-void/) spell from the Advanced Class Guide sounds like it might be what you're thinking of, since it does allow you to see through supernatural darkness.

I usually think of the Daylight spell as the solution for supernatural darkness - it doesn't work like you're describing, though it does have the benefit of working for everyone rather than a single person.

The Echolocation spell doesn't technically let you see in the dark, but it does grant 40 ft. of sound-based blindsight, which might make a good substitute.

As for magic items, the only one that I've found that grants the ability to see in supernatural darkness is the very expensive [Rod of Shadows](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/rods/rod-of-shadows/), which you might not be able to use at the same time as a ranged weapon. There's also an advanced rogue talent that allows a rogue who already has darkvision to upgrade it to the [See In Darkness](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/rogue/rogue-talents/paizo-rogue-advanced-talents/see-in-darkness-su/) ability and see through supernatural darkness.

Answer (score 1):

There now also exists the [Fey Form II](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/f/fey-form/) spell, which allows polymorphing into a fey creature with See in Darkness. It is available for some classes as a level 5 spell.